# PHP how to detect the change of variable?

Tags: php

Is PHP exists a function that detect the change of variable?
That is something like this:

```
//called when $a is changed.
function variableChanged($value) {
    echo "value changed to " . $value;
}

$a = 1;
//attach the variable to the method.
$a.attachTo("variableChanged");
$a = 2;
$a = 3;

//expected output:
//value changed to 2
//value changed to 3
```

I know that it is easy to achieve if I use the "setter" method. But since I am working on some existing codes, I am not able to modify them. Can somebody tell me how to achieve my purpose? Thanks.

Comment: The short answer is it's not possible (except with a debugger). What is your use case, why do you need this?

Comment: PHP execution is linear not event based so I don't think you can do that.

Comment: This is a very peculiar thing to need, in most cases.

Comment: This looks like an instance of the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Now I am working on an existing system which is in a large scale for me. The case is: a variable is passed through a number of messy functions, and I wish to trace how the value of variable changes during the flow. I am just looking for a convenient method instead of tracing it line by line.

Comment: if you can't refactor the _messy functions_ into clean objects and implement `unit tests`, try my answer. instead of `$myVar` you just pass `$test->myVar` through your messy functions

Comment: @Pekka웃 it IS possible through magic methods without a debugger

Comment: @DanFromGermany sure, but what's the point? What the OP seems to need *is* a debugger.

Comment: @Pekka웃 you are right,.. debugger is what he needs. do you know why in my answer on passing the `$test->xxx` to `messyFunction` it stops registering changes?

Comment: @Dan hmm, interesting question! Apparently the setter isn't fired in that case, which might be a bug? Not sure. Might be worth a separate SO question (if one doesn't exist already)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> know that it is easy to achieve if I use the "setter" method. But since I am working on some existing codes, I am not able to modify them.

I assume that you can change *some* code, but not the object / class you are working with. If you cannot change any code at all this question would be useless.

What you can do is make your own class, **extending** the class you are working with, and adding your setter there. For all purposes you can not-override the parent setting, except for a magic setter on whatever you need to track. Track changes and then call the **parent functions**, so no changes in any other internal workings will be in effect.

Answer (score 3):

This could only be achieved by wrapping your variable within a class, and implementing a onchange yourself.

ie.

```
class MyVarContainer {
    var $internalVar = array();

    function __get($name) {
        return !empty($this->internalVar[$name]) $this->internalVar[$name] ? FALSE;
    }

    function __set($name, $value) {
       $oldval = $this->$name;
       $this->internalVar[$name] = $value;

       if($oldval !== FALSE) {
          onUpdated($name, $oldval, $value);
       } else {
          onCreated($name, $value);
       }
    }

    function onCreated($name, $value) {

    }

    function onUpdated($name, $oldvalue, $newvalue) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Besides using a `debugger`:

> The SplObserver interface is used alongside SplSubject to implement
>   the Observer Design Pattern. 
>   http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.splobserver.php

Or the magic methods `__get()` and `__set()`: Encapsulating the variable into a class, you could implement a event handler yourself and register the change of a variable. **Also you could attach callbacks like here**:

```
<?php
header("content-type: text/plain");

class WatchVar {
    private $data = array();
    private $org = array();
    private $callbacks = array();

    public function __set($name, $value) {
        if (!array_key_exists($name, $this->data)) {
            $this->org[$name] = $value;
        } else {
            //variable gets changed again!
            $this->triggerChangedEvent($name, $value);
        }
        $this->data[$name] = $value;
    }

    public function &__get($name) {
        if (array_key_exists($name, $this->data)) {
            if ($this->data[$name] != $this->org[$name]) {
                //variable has changed, return original
                //return $this->org[$name];
                //or return new state:
                return $this->data[$name];
            } else {
                //variable has not changed
                return $this->data[$name];
            }
        }
    }

    public function addCallback($name, $lambdaFunc) {
        $this->callbacks[$name] = $lambdaFunc;
    }

    protected function triggerChangedEvent($name, $value) {
        //$this->data[$name] has been changed!
        //callback call like:
        call_user_func($this->callbacks[$name], $value);
    }
}


$test = new WatchVar;
$test->addCallback('xxx', function($newValue) { echo "xxx has changed to {$newValue}\n"; });
$test->xxx = "aaa";

echo $test->xxx . "\n";
//output: aaa

$test->xxx = "bbb";
//output: xxx has changed to bbb

echo $test->xxx . "\n";
//output bbb

function messyFunction(&$var) {
    $var = "test";
}

messyFunction($test->xxx);
//output:
```

Answer (score 1):

You could revised your code as simple like this just to produce that expected output you want.

```
function variableChanged($value) {
    return "value changed to " . $value;
    }

    $a = 1;

    echo $a = variableChanged(2);
    echo '<br/>';
    echo $a = variablechanged(3);

=================
//output
value changed to 2
value changed to 3
```

or using a class like this....

```
class VariableHandler{

        private $Variable;


        function setVariable($initialValue = NULL){
            $this->Variable = $initialValue;
            return $initialValue;
        }

        function changeValue($newValue = NULL){
            $this->Variable = $newValue;
            return "value has change to ". $newValue;
        }


    }

    $var = new VariableHandler;

    echo $a = $var->setVariable(1);
    echo '<br/>';
    echo $var->changeValue(2);
    echo '<br/>';
    echo $var->changeValue(3);

 =================
    //output
    value changed to 2
    value changed to 3
```