# PHP: passing class member by reference not working

Tags: php, events, event-handling

Someone asked for an event handler that registeres variable changes in this question: [PHP how to detect the change of variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17543124/php-how-to-detect-the-change-of-variable)

I tried to develop a quick class with PHP's magic functions `__get` and `__set`. This works until I pass the member into a normal function by reference, it does not trigger the event anymore.

Is this a bug, or something that is not possible, or do I just miss something?

```
<?php
header("content-type: text/plain");

class WatchVar {
    private $data = array();
    private $org = array();
    private $callbacks = array();

    public function __set($name, $value) {
        if (!array_key_exists($name, $this->data)) {
            $this->org[$name] = $value;
        } else {
            //variable gets changed again!
            $this->triggerChangedEvent($name, $value);
        }
        $this->data[$name] = $value;
    }

    public function &__get($name) {
        if (array_key_exists($name, $this->data)) {
            if ($this->data[$name] != $this->org[$name]) {
                //variable has changed, return original
                //return $this->org[$name];
                //or return new state:
                return $this->data[$name];
            } else {
                //variable has not changed
                return $this->data[$name];
            }
        }
    }

    public function addCallback($name, $lambdaFunc) {
        $this->callbacks[$name] = $lambdaFunc;
    }

    protected function triggerChangedEvent($name, $value) {
        //$this->data[$name] has been changed!
        //callback call like:
        call_user_func($this->callbacks[$name], $value);
    }
}


$test = new WatchVar;
$test->addCallback('xxx', function($newValue) { echo "xxx has changed to {$newValue}\n"; });
$test->xxx = "aaa";

echo $test->xxx . "\n";
//output: aaa

$test->xxx = "bbb";
//output: xxx has changed to bbb

echo $test->xxx . "\n";
//output bbb

function messyFunction(&$var) {
    $var = "test";
}

messyFunction($test->xxx);
//output: nothing, why?
```

Comment: There is no output because you do not output anything. You have to use `echo`.

Comment: Why not simply use [SPL's Observer pattern classes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.splobserver.php)

Comment: @str the echo is in the callback: `echo "xxx has changed to {$newValue}\n";` - when `messyFunction()` changes the object member, the callback should be triggered like in the lines before

Comment: @MarkBaker I did not try all the new Spl functions yet, I will def have a look into them! Besides, I'd like to know what's wrong with my code, I want to understand why it does not work

Comment: Why does it matter why it doesn't work? The code you already have clearly shows that no one would **want** this to work. It's a hack. It's ugly, full of magic and adds needless complexity. If you want to do event-driven programming, use established design patterns, like Subject/Observer, EventDispatcher, Signal/Slot and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Altering this code it works:

```
function messyFunction(&$var) {
    $var->xxx = "test";
}

messyFunction($test);
//output: xxx has changed to test
```

> **//output: nothing, why?**

Even passed by reference, the function only recieves a clone of the member variable instead of the instance + magic functions.