# Php run method on property change

Tags: php, class, object, methods, properties

Is it possible to run php method on property change? Like shown in the example below:

**Class:**

```
class MyClass
{
    public MyProperty;

    function __onchange($this -> MyProperty)
    {
        echo "MyProperty changed to " . $this -> MyProperty;
    }        
}
```

**Object:**

```
$MyObject = new MyClass;
$MyObject -> MyProperty = 1;
```

**Result:**

```
 "MyProperty changed to 1"
```

Comment: Put the variable as private and use a function to change it.

Comment: You'll have to implement it. E.g Change the property, trigger the event and capture the event.

Comment: Of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17543256/3303195

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like @lucas said, if you can set your property as private within the class, you can then use the __set() to detect a change.

```
class MyClass
{
  private $MyProperty;

  function __set($name, $value)
  {
     if(property_exists('MyClass', $name)){
       echo "Property". $name . " modified";
     }
  }

 }


$r = new MyClass;
$r->MyProperty = 1; //Property MyProperty changed.
```

Comment: Good one but affects all private properties

Comment: It's not called when changing a property from within the class. Any ideas on how to do such thing?

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this best by using a setter method.

```
class MyClass
{
    private MyProperty;

    public function setMyProperty($value)
    {
        $this->MyProperty = $value;
        echo "MyProperty changed to " . $this -> MyProperty;
    }

}
```

Now you simply call the setter instead of setting the value yourself.

```
$MyObject = new MyClass;
$MyObject -> setMyProperty(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the [magic method `__set`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.set):

```
class Foo {

    protected $bar;

    public function __set($name, $value) {
        echo "$name changed to $value";
        $this->$name = $value;
    }

}

$f = new Foo;
$f->bar = 'baz';
```

It may be a better and more conventional idea to use a good old-fashioned setter instead:

```
class Foo {

    protected $bar;

    public function setBar($value) {
        echo "bar changed to $value";
        $this->bar = $value;
    }

}

$f = new Foo;
$f->setBar('baz');
```

Answer (score -1):

This post is quite old, but I have to deal with the same issue and a typical class with multiple fields. Why using private properties ?
Here is what I implemented :

```php
class MyClass {

    public $foo;
    public $bar;

    function __set($name, $value) {
        if(!property_exists('MyClass', $name)){ // security
            return;
        }
        if ('foo' == $name) { // test on the property needed to avoid firing 
                              // "change event" on every private properties
            echo "Property " . $name . " modified";
        }
        $this->$name = $value;
    }

}

$r = new MyClass();
$r->bar = 12;
$r->foo = 1; //Property foo changed.
var_dump($r);
/*
object(MyClass)[1]
  public 'foo' => int 1
  public 'bar' => int 12
*/
```

Comment: This won't work since the foo property has to be either protected or private for the setter to be called. If public it will just change the value and bypass the __set method.