# php magic setters - modified child properties

Tags: php

Lets say, we have the following PHP class:

```
class Product {
    protected $data = array();
    protected $modified = false;

    public function __construct($data) {
        $this->data = $data;
    }

    public function & __get($name) {
        if(array_key_exists($name, $this->data)) {
            return $this->data->$name;
        }

        $null = null;

        return $null;
    }

    public function __set($name, $value) {
        $this->data->$name = $value;
        $this->modified = true;
    }        
}
$obj = new Product([]);
```

If I now set a value (for example `$obj->name = "Name";`), the class property $modified is set to true. Thats what I want to achive.

But is it somehow possible, to "track" modifications, if the are done in object values? For example:

```
$property = new stdClass();
$property->name = "Name of Prop";
$obj = new Product([
    "name" => "Name",
    "someObject" => $property
]);

// Now here comes the change
$obj->someObject->name = "New Name";
```

Because with the code above, $obj->modified would be false

Comment: Maybe I was on the wrong path here, check this one out, I guess its what youre looking for:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17543124/php-how-to-detect-the-change-of-variable

Comment: I would build a whole new class for $property instead of using stdClass(), that would be much easier to maintain the code later and you can then implement what you're looking for easily.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you have to pass the new value to the "set" function. The way you do it just changes the value itself without going into your function where you declared, that "modified" turns true.

Like this maybe?

```
$obj->someObject->__set($name, 'New Name');
```